# How to connect managed sql database and restore backup from storage account using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

How to connect managed sql database and restore backup from storage account using Powershell.

My backup is in storage account fileshare e,g:

```
servername: demosql.nodesquare.com
dbname: testdb
sqlusername: adminuser
sqlpassword: Abcd123456789
storageaccountname: teststorage01
fileshare: abc.bak
```

First I want to connect to storageaccount and share and create backup url and then connect to managed sqldb and restore abc.bak.

Please help me how I can do it using Powershell?

Below is my script I tried but it didn't work:

```
servername: demosql.nodesquare.com
dbname: testdb
sqlusername: adminuser
sqlpassword: Abcd123456789
storageaccountname: teststorage01
fileshare: abc.bak
```

Below is my script I tried but didn't worked:

```
Get the Azure Storage account context
$context = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroupName -AccountName $AzureStorageAccountName
$storageAccountKey = $context[0].Value

$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $AzureStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

$share = Get-AzStorageShare -Name $FileShareName -Context $StorageContext

# Get the list of .bak files and sort by last modified timestamp
$backupFiles = $share | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.bak" } | Sort-Object LastModified -Descending
if ($backupFiles.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "No backup files found."
}
else {
    # Get the latest backup file
    $latestBackup = $backupFiles[0]

    # Construct the backup file URL
    $backupFilePath = "/" + $FileShareName + "/" + $latestBackup.Name
    $backupFileUrl = "https://" + $AzureStorageAccountName + ".file.core.windows.net" + $backupFilePath
    $backupFileUrl
```

For managed DB connection I am unable to get exact commands to connect

Comment: Powershell 2? Really?

Comment: Are you still using PowerShell 2.0? The one that was introduced in 2008? It's not even listed in the [PowerShell End-of-support dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/powershell-support-lifecycle#powershell-end-of-support-dates) matrix any more.

Comment: I am using below version
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.1778